# PHP: How to get a fully qualified class name from an alias?

Tags: php, class, namespaces, alias

In PHP, if I want to get the fully qualified class name of a class that's included with a `use` statement, how do I do that? For instance,

```
<?php
namespace MyNamespace;

use Namespace\To\Class as MyClass;

function getNamespaceOfMyClass() {
    // Return ??
}

echo getNamespaceOfMyClass();
```

I know one way is to do `get_class(new MyClass())`, but what if I can't/don't want to make an instance of `MyClass`? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: @AlexP: There are perfectly valid reasons to do this. One of them would be when you want to instruct a DI container on how to resolve a specific type.

Comment: @Jon I did not say anything about it being invalid. I want to know more information as it's a contrived example.

Comment: @AlexP My specific use case is in Zend Framework 2, where we have an EventManager whose events are attached to the fully qualified class name of the class. The code I'm refactoring looks not so nice—it uses things like: `use Account\Document\Profile;` and then: `get_class(new Profile());` to do this job, for instance, which is less than ideal. I want a vanilla way of doing that, preferably not requiring PHP 5.5.

Comment: @OmarDiab I see the dilemma, I have the same issue when trying to call entities from an `ObjectManager()->getEntityRepository($className)` where I don't want to hard code the class. I tend to use a number of static variables defined in an entity service layer (e.g. `static::ENTITY_CLASS_NAME_PROFILE = 'Namespace/entity/Profile';`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In PHP 5.5 onwards you can do this using [`::class`](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.new-features.php#migration55.new-features.class-name):

```
echo MyClass::class;
```

Unfortunately this is not possible at all on earlier versions, where you have to either hardcode the class name or create an instance first and use `get_class` on it.

Comment: Awesome, didn't know that! Unfortunate that there aren't ways in earlier versions, I'll hold out for a bit and see if anyone else has any tricks.

Comment: What can I do if my class name is a variable (a string)? i.e. `($prefix . 'Class')::class` doesn't work! Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Roubi if you have the class name in a string then it already has to be fully qualified, otherwise you can't do anything useful with it. What's the use case?

Comment: it's for dynamic creation of a form with Symfony3, but you made me realize the right way might be to "manually" add the namespace in the string. I was just curious to know if there was a way to be lazy, but it's pointless. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @myol `::class` in the first line is that link, or are you looking for something else?

Comment: @Jon I have the same question as Roubi. My use case is that all class names are cached in the framework I am using, and I would like to cache the full class names for things to work properly. https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/5/src/Core/Manifest/ClassManifest.php#L542

Answer (score 5):

On early PHP version (that is, PHP < 5.5) you can get the class name via [Reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) API, like this:

```
namespace App\Core;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type;

class MyClass {}

$refclass = new \ReflectionClass(new Type\DateType);
print $refclass->getName();
$refclass = new \ReflectionClass(new MyClass());
print $refclass->getName();
```

Of course, if this is not expensive for your case.

**Note**
Since PHP 5.4:

```
$classname = (new \ReflectionClass(new Type\DateType))->getName();
```