# ::class equivalent in PHP 5.4

Tags: php, php-5.4

I've got a PHP script with the following line:

```
$class = Connection::class;
```

This runs as expected on PHP 5.5 as explained here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class. However, it causes a syntax error in PHP 5.4.

Is there a simple way that I can rewrite this line to run in PHP 5.4?

Comment: _However, it causes a syntax error in PHP 5.4._ Go on, give us a clue, **what error** And a bit of code from the class definition would be useful too!

Comment: I'd imagine the error to be "unexpected T_CLASS" ...

Comment: Yes, that's the error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in ...`

Comment: Check the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34181247/1529532

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this does it for you:

```
$class = __NAMESPACE__ ."\\".get_class($connection_object);
```